# Android : Will Gcm changes the JSON format?

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging

This is the JSON data format sending by the server.

[image]

```
{  
"s":1,
"es":true,
"event":{  
  "completed":0,
  "pid":"13",
  "eid":"8",
  "event_start":"2015-03-09 05:30",
  "event_end":"2015-03-09 06:30",
  "event_type":"3",
  "event_state":"1",
  "followup_location":"hyderabad",
  "notes":"test",
  "person_met":"ANAND MS",
  "id":"521",
  "cid":null,
  "rid":null,
  "sid":null,
  "actual_start":null,
  "actual_end":null,
  "followup_date":null,
  "recording_path":null,
  "predecessor_id":null
},
"gcm":"   {\"multicast_id\":6761581515287135985,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1419657430616237%752516a3f9fd7ecd\"}]}",
"msg":{  
  "contacts":[  
     {  
        "id":"6",
        "short_name":"AND",
        "salutation":"Mr",
        "first_name":"ANAND",
        "last_name":"MS",
        "sex":"M",
        "dob":"2014-07-09",
        "company_name":"SWAAS",
        "company_address":"",
        "designation":"",
        "management_level":"",
        "financial_capacity":"",
        "status":null,
        "email":null,
        "door":null,
        "block":null,
        "flat_name":null,
        "floor":null,
        "street_name":null,
        "locality_name":null,
        "city":null,
        "pincode":null,
        "state":null,
        "landmark":null,
        "client_type":null,
        "notes":null,
        "lead_source1":null,
        "lead_source2":null,
        "lead_source3":null,
        "lead_source_other":null,
        "lead_source3_name":null
     }
  ],
  "project":{  
     "id":"13",
     "name":"NewProject-AnandMS",
     "short_name":"MS-Project",
     "address":"       Chennai 600041 ",
     "requirements":null,
     "status":"1",
     "stage":"1",
     "lat":null,
     "lng":null,
     "project_size":null,
     "remarks":"",
     "city":null,
     "pincode":null,
     "door":null,
     "block":null,
     "flat_name":null,
     "floor":null,
     "street_name":null,
     "locality_name":null,
     "state":null,
     "landmark":null,
     "project":null
  }
},
"ids":[  
  "APA91bGllNaF9ESQrjJwux7GDDCEGw-L_6leIfOwLUVBpD0IsxvzIEFoRxA5KDLU4xTT7SwqBNz5fcVyHK492waOMJTE9F7JNOhlae6Y7_4UsUCOQb9BPSvBsA81GgvxURcPhkcczkDrITMiAhhHM1kQPm7GmAqgDg"
 ]
 }
```

and this is what the JSON data format I'am receiving.

```
[  
 {  
  project= {  
     "project_size":null,
     "status":"1",
     "street_name":null,
     "state":null,
     "locality_name":null,
     "block":null,
     "door":null,
     "lng":null,
     "remarks":"",
     "short_name":"MS-Project",
     "requirements":null,
     "stage":"1",
     "city":null,
     "pincode":null,
     "id":"13",
     "project":null,
     "landmark":null,
     "floor":null,
     "address":"       Chennai 600041 ",
     "name":"NewProject-AnandMS",
     "flat_name":null,
     "lat":null
  },
  from=467190216700,
  event=      {  
     "person_met":"ANAND MS",
     "sid":null,
     "predecessor_id":null,
     "event_state":"1",
     "followup_date":null,
     "event_type":"3",
     "recording_path":null,
     "pid":"13",
     "eid":"8",
     "cid":null,
     "id":"521",
     "actual_end":null,
     "rid":null,
     "event_end":"2015-03-09 06:30",
     "followup_location":"hyderabad",
     "actual_start":null,
     "notes":"test",
     "event_start":"2015-03-09 05:30",
     "completed":0
  },
  android.support.content.wakelockid=1,
  collapse_key=do_not_collapse
 }
]
```

This is the code what I have written to Gcm message.

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    context = getApplicationContext();
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
         * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
         * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
         * don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            System.out.println("gcmbundle"+extras.toString());
            sendNotification("New Contact Received ");                  
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
         }      
    }
 }
```

I don't know that why I'am receiving `project =` or `event =` in JSON format. Some information has also not received properly. thank you for reading and helping :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 The JSON format is changing when the Gcm receives the data. Yes updated my question.

Comment: This json should be coming from your server not GCM. Your server sends data to GCM which forward to the devices.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Yes The format is changing When am receiving the data by using Gcm. Server sends it correctly.

Comment: I don't think GCM will change the data on its own. Check your server code which sends data

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Please check the image. I'am getting the data correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67742/discussion-between-user3764346-and-rohit5k2).

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of GCM Connection Servers, one is Cloud Connection Server also known as XMPP and other one is HTTP.

In GCM HTTP JSON mesages are sent as POST

```
{ "collapse_key": "score_update",
"time_to_live": 108,
"delay_while_idle": true,
"data": {
"score": "4x8",
"time": "15:16.2342"
},
"registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

and in CSS the JSON messages are encapsulated in XMPP messages

```
<message id="">
<gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
{
  "to":"REGISTRATION_ID",  // "to" replaces "registration_ids"
  "message_id":"m-1366082849205" // new required field
  "data":
  {
      "hello":"world",
  }
  "time_to_live":"600",
  "delay_while_idle": true/false,
  "delivery_receipt_requested": true/false
}
</gcm>
</message>
```

I am not sure which of the two you are using, but if you just want to send push notifications from your server to your app through GCM server, I would recomment using HTTP GCM server, because it would give you the JSON response in the exact format as been sent by your server.

Hope this would help!!